# Assign click event to a wxPanel instance

Tags: c++, events, wxwidgets

I have a wxPanel class. I need every instance of that class handle a click event. Is that possible in wxWidgets? So far, I always had to use window IDs to assign events to objects (eg. buttons).
However this wxPanel is about to occur multiplicatively on the screen, so I need to avoid using window ID.

The class:

### panel.h

```
class UVStatusPanel : public wxPanel
{

public:
    UVStatusPanel(wxFrame* parent, int pos);

    void paintEvent(wxPaintEvent& evt);
    void paintNow();

    //THIS is expected to be the event function
    void onClick(wxCommandEvent& WXUNUSED(event));

    bool State(bool state);
    bool State();

    DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()
private:
    bool painting;
    bool state;
    void render(wxDC &dc);
};
```

### panel.cpp

```
/**The constructor*/
UVStatusPanel::UVStatusPanel(wxFrame* parent, int pos) :
wxPanel(parent)
{
 /** some align and draw rect code was there**/
 //My two attepmts to assign the click event to the panel
 Connect(this->m_windowId, wxEVT_COMMAND_LEFT_CLICK, 
          wxCommandEventHandler(UVStatusPanel::onClick));
 //EVT_COMMAND_LEFT_CLICK(this->m_windowId,UVStatusPanel::onFocus);
}
```

Currently noc clicks are registered. Can anyone explain how click events work in wxWidgets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wxEVT_COMMAND_LEFT_CLICK` is not generated by `wxPanel` (nor by almost anything else, to be honest), the event you are looking for is called `wxEVT_LEFT_UP` and it's a `wxMouseEvent`, not a `wxCommandEvent`.

Also, the use of both event table and `Connect()` in your example is not recommended. It does work but risks being confusing, just pick one and stick with it (preferably `Connect()` or, if you use 2.9+, `Bind()`).